Moving a vent pipe
We are moving our fridge back in the wall so it is aligned with our cabinets and not sticking out. We have a vent pipe in the wall that is in the way. Can we move it to the right and use the same configuration that is there now.

A photo would help

There's not enough information here to answer. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

A general answer is, Yes. However it is important to know what is above the wall. Second floor? Just attic and roof?
A vent can be moved and have a run horizontal as long as there is 1/4 per foot tilt to the drain end.  Follow that, and you are ok, assuming there isn't any other plumbing drain above that will be affected.

Only the attic above it. It is also the vent pipe for our kitchen sink.  The pipe goes up wall and across the basement wall to the vent pipe outside.

As long as you maintain the same horizontal connections (shorten or extend anything that's currently connected), it should be possible.  But you just said it goes across the basement wall and mentioned an attic ... what exactly does that mean?
